# When is a subset called a subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it necessary for an element to be kept in braces if we want to separate it from a set and make the element subset of the same set?
Like in...

$$A= \{a,b,c\}$$

If we want to make the element $a$ above a subset of $A$, is it then necessary to take out *a* from *A* and write it separately as $\{a\}.$

Comment: Dont make it so difficult.  A set is a collection of elements.  We use the notation of brackets to denote sets.  If you want a set that contains just the element $a$ we would write it as $\{a\}$.

Comment: However I *must* be a hard-ass and point out that "If we want to make the element a above a subset of A," is meaningless nonsense.  The element of $a$ is itself.  You can not make it become anything else.  And it is not a set (so  far as we know) and it is not a subset of $A$.  And you can't make it one.  Instead you can "make a subset of A that only has $a$ as an element".  And that is $\{a\}$.

Comment: @fleablood Perfect explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to show the elements of the set, you put the elements in braces and use the symbol $\subset$.

For example $$\{ 2,4,6,8,10\} \subset \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$ means that $$\{ 2,4,6,8,10\}$$ is a subset of $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$

Comment: What if I simply write 2,4,6,8,10  without any braces? Will then that be called 2,4,6,8,10 'belongs to' {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89,10}?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Then you call them elements. Yes you can say they belong to the set and the notation is $2\in A $

Comment: 2,4,5,8, 10 written without any braces is five different things typed out next to each other  on a computer screen.  That's it.

Answer (score 2):

$a$ is an *element* of $A$. $\{a\}$ is a *subset* of $A$. The set of all subsets of $A$ is

$$\{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$$

Comment: In place of symbol for empty set which you have written as {} above, can we write \empty set?

Comment: It's better to write it as $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing`) to avoid confusion with [the Greek letter phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi).

Comment: \varnothing $\mapsto \varnothing$ and \emptyset $\mapsto \emptyset$.  And \phi $\mapsto \phi$.  I don't think there will be much confusion.

Comment: @fleablood I'm talking about what the reader will see, not the underlying markup.

Comment: So am I.  $\emptyset$ vs. $\phi$.  I don't think there will be much confusion (and if there is any $\varnothing$ does not escape it).  But that wasn't the point I was trying to make.  I just wanted to show the reader how to make the symbols is all.

Comment: Using the Greek letter phi for the empty set is [highly discouraged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22799/81964). There's a reason the empty set has its own symbol.